# UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE when installing npm package

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I updated npm a few days ago. I get the following error when I try to install parcel-bundler.

```
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/parcel-bundler failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/js-yaml failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
```

I tried setting strict-ssl to false . I get the following error.

```
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 npmjsorgcoachpage - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/parcel-bundler
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy.
```

```
npm version 6.13.4
```

```
node version v12.14.1
```